# ElasticSearch reindex reasons

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm migrating to elasticSearch and wanna find out some questions.
I am gonna use static + dynamic mapping (static type for fields, which I will use for filtering during the search, will not change their types in the future). As I understand I can put different data to index and then change it. Example:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "secondName": "Smith",
  "age": 20,
  "params" : [
    {
      "a": "b",
      "c": "d"
    },
    {
      "m": "n"
    }
  ]
}
```

and then change this record to:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "secondName": "Smith",
  "age": "20",
  "newparams": [
    {
      "a": "b",
      "c": "d"
    },
    {
      "m": "n"
    }
  ]
}
```

So I can do it without reindexing. I can change fields, can add new so what are the reasons, which force me to do reindex?

**Editing**

The main goal is to use elastic instead of DB to enhance performance. There will be storage and I will only retrieve info from it. The search will depend on some fields with static mapping, I will no change their types. But in the future, I possible need to add some field or something like this, and I wanna know which my actions lead me to need to reindex?

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch provides an reindex api which does this kind of things internally, take a look [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html). Alternative you can also update your documents with the [update](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) api.

Comment: Ok, I saw this page, there is a description of reindexing. I wanna avoid it in the future, that's why I wanna to know all `reasons` of reindexing to build the elastic structure in the right way.

Comment: If your data contains some new property that has no deterministic way how you can calculate it from the properties ur data has by now, you will need to reindex it.

Comment: Maybe my question was not so clear, I've added some explanation

Comment: You can add a field to an existing index without any issue (and update older documents with this new field if needed) but as elastic "type" with the mappings and index fields according to this mappings, you cant change the mappings of an existing fields, you have to reindex your documents then.

Comment: Exact that I need! So the only restriction is not to change the existing field's types and send values with appropriate types, right?

Comment: Indeed, you cant modify exising mappings but you can add new fields.